# Redirect after registration in Dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

DNN: 07.00.06

Using the standard DNN registration form, redirection does not take place. I have my registration page permission so that registered users cannot view it, so after a new user signs up, they're greeted with a "You do not have access to view this page within the website" message.

I turned off partial rendering and added javascript to search for this message and redirect to the homepage accordingly but it's a bit of a hack job.

I have set the redirect after registration to the home page specifically in the settings. Tried other pages, tried turning it off.

I do see this was a bug in the DNN tracker, but does anyone know of a cleaner workaround? I don't want to use a third party registration module for this purpose.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall earlier versions of DNN7 had problems with redirect after registration. I would encourage you to try the latest DNN release.